# How to get a weekday in Globalize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-globalization, jquery-globalize

In my project, I am using [Globalize 1.1.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize.js).

It has the globalize for weekday in this path "dates/calendars/gregorian/days", I don't know how to get a specific day.

Like I want to get the Globalize for "Thuesday", the field is called "thu".

So my question is, How do I do it?

I had tried:

- Globalize.dateParser({ raw: "weekday/wide" })( "thu" )
- Globalize.formatUnit(1, "days", { form: "wide" })
- Globalize.formatMessage("/dates/calendars/gregorian/days/wide/thu")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use CLDR data directly

```
var dayNames = Globalize.cldr.main('dates/calendars/gregorian/days/format/wide');

// Access Thursday
dayNames.thu;

// Unrelated to question, but first day of week might be useful as well
var firstDay = dayNames[Globalize.cldr.supplemental.weekData.firstDay()];
```

### Use date formatters

... or rely on date calculations, which are less dependent on cldr as noted by Rafael Xavier in this [globalizejs issue](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/491#issuecomment-134997524) on github.

So you would create a date, which you know is Tuesday, and specify a format giving you the weekday:

```
var formatter = Globalize.dateFormatter({raw: "EEEE"});
formatter(new Date(0, 0, 2));
```